# Way of touchpad shielding

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I have a touchpad in my computer which is a little bit too wide and I constantly touch it with part of my left hand during writing, as a result cursor move to the random location in text editor. There is some setup in the driver which theoretically should prevent occurrence of such an issue, however it does not work in my case (i.e. the way in which it is implemented in the driver give unsatisfactory results). I'm searching for a way in which I will be able to physically shield the part of the touchpad which is causing an issue. I did some experiments and it seems to me that 6 mm high pile of paper, stick on the surface of left side of touchpad is able to do the job, however 6mm is too high and I have the feeling that it if I keep it, then it will break my display.

Do you have and suggestion of materials which can be used (something easily accessible) or maybe some external software components which can be applied (I cannot do it at the level of my current driver).

Comment: Just a question, is using a mouse, and disabling the touchpad temporarily (the preferred way of dealing with this kind of problem) not an option? There's a keyboard combination or button to toggle the touchpad.

Comment: If the touchpad isn't used uninstalling the device will disable it.

Comment: As far as I remember, some touchpad driver allowed to configure "dead zones". Check if yours has this feature.

Comment: @LPChip I do not use mouse, I use only touchpad.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not have it in my driver

Comment: @Darqer - If the touchpad works then you have the device and driver installed for it.  Your last comment does not make a great deal of sense.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean touchpad works (as it should) I have driver installed, however this driver does not have an option which lets me set up dead zone (I know that in synaptics touchpad you can do it, this is apls), therefore I serach for mechanical way.

Comment: So update your question with that relevant information.  Because your comment was addressed to me and said something entirely different than what you just said.

Comment: @Ramhound OK I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always save time and effort by disabling the touchpad on the computer and buy an external one.

Comment: I carry my computer around a lot, so it would not be an option, no external parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can shield the touchpad from yourself with conductive foil.  Put a layer of insulator (eg paper) down first, then the foil, all with enough adhesive that it doesn't move at all.  And the foil probably needs to be grounded  (a small wire to some shield ground on your computer).  This will 100% work.

However, it might break the touchpad so it doesn't work right, even on the unshielded area.  (It may need to be power cycled to work as well as it is going to work.)